# Requiring a package doesn't find a dependency

Tags: commerce, composer

When running `HOME=/home/gymsagec composer require "drupal/commerce 8.2.x-dev"`, I get this error message:

> drupal/commerce 8.2.x-dev requires commerceguys/intl dev-master -> no matching package found

I can install the intl package by itself using composer but even after doing that, running the first script fails. Why?

Comment: After the manual install, did you clear caches and load the site through a browser to rebuild the cache? Could also be some typos in the code.

Comment: This is Composer, site caches have no effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in [Composer fails when installing a dependency of a dependency, but not when the dependency is installed directly.](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1478) that probably happens because the root composer.json file doesn't set a minimum stability, or doesn't accept a less stable package.

Try with `composer require drupal/commerce:@dev` as suggested in that issue report.

Comment: That installed a dev version of commerce for drupal 7... `Installing drupal/commerce (dev-7.x-1.x fe5c4f8)`

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a minimum stability issue. We might need an extra note on docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/install.html

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue. Downloaded a fresh Drupal 8.1.1, ran the two commands from the "existing sites" part of drupal commerce docs, and it worked fine.